# How to insert a line break every five rows in Excel/Word/Notepad++?

Tags: regex, excel, replace, notepad++, newline

I have this list:

08:17 
17:01 
08:09 
16:56 
09:22 
17:01 
08:08 
17:05 
07:59 
16:54 
.
.
.

**How do I insert a linebreak each 5 rows In Excel/Word/Notepad? (not < br >)**

For example:

08:17 
17:01 
08:09 
16:56 
09:22 
(line break here) 
08:08 
17:05 
07:59 
16:54 
08:02 
(line break here) 
etc 
etc

I've tried the /n/r/n/r but can't figure it out, do I have to use code or is there a tool like TextFX/Notepad++ or anything that has this feature?

Comment: For Excel, I would recommend recording a macro. If you get stuck post here the code that you tried and the problems that you are facing and then we will take it from there. What say? ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Notepad++ find/replace in regex mode:

```
Find: ((.*\s*\n\s*){5})

Replace: $1\n
```

Cheers.

Comment: thanks a lot its working! by the way how do you insert 2 lines instead of 1?

Comment: @pnuts +1 from me back at ya... and on it goes this thing of ours

Answer (score 2):

Distinctly more tedious in Excel! I'd suggest:

- Enter `x` in the right hand of any two adjacent spare columns, in the second row that contains your 6th item (here the second instance of 17:01).
- Select that cell and the five immediately above it, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> depressed, copy down that block down as far as required.
- Subtotal the column containing `x`. Copy/Paste Special/Values that column (should have moved to the right) then delete it and the column immediately to its left. Subtotal again with Remove All.

Answer (score 0):

Word's regex is not popular but Find what: `(?{35})` and replace with `\1^p` seems to work for me, when started immediately before your first character (ie the 0 in 08:17). {NB Use wildcards}

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but I thought I should throw in the sorting trick, since it's quick and doesn't require pasting out of Excel. (Though I am fond of using Notepad++ for a quick regex hack, it's a pain if you want to maintain your formatting.)

Create a temporary column next to your data and autofill with consecutive numbers 1, 2, 3... to the bottom of your data.

Then continue the column below your data, with 5, 10, 15... until you get to a number greater than the size of your data.

Finally, sort everything on the temporary column and voila, skipped rows.